# Failed to start the Dart CLI isolate (null). in mac

Tags: flutter, dart

When I am doing flutter pub get I am getting this issue, In flutter doctor no issue is coming, can anyone please help me for me the information you can see the image.

[Issue image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jMRU.png)

Comment: Yes. I had the same issue on Linux and even I wasn't able to open programs placed in `/snap`. I think that was a bug of dart itself. Delete and re-install of `dart & flutter` does not really helped me, so I re-install whole OS.

Answer (score 7):

I always get this issue.

What I do is

1. Go to **flutter** directory where you installed the flutter
2. Go to /bin/cache
3. remove all the items inside the cache directory

run `flutter clean` in the project root directory

then you are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

you can try following,

1. Delete the pub cache folder from C:\Users{your
   username}\AppData\Roaming\Pub.
2. Delete all the packages folders in your project (also in
   subfolders).
3. Delete the pubspec.lock file in your project.
4. Run pub get again from a command line or select Tools in the Dart
   Editor menu, and then select Pub Get.

   [reference](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/web-development/9781783989621/1/ch01lvl1sec17/solving-problems-when-pub-get-fails)

Answer (score 0):

I face this problem and tried many solutions but none of them worked.

and the last solution was to update the Dart SDK.

if you face problems when you update the Dart SDK.

1. try to update Dart SDK you should go [Dart SDK Download](https://dart.dev/get-dart/archive) and download it
2. go to the location you set up Dart SDK and delete the old version of Dart SDK
3. Extract the new version of Dart SDK [Like The Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5jtN.png).
4. Make sure that the path of dart SDK in Windows Environment Variables is the Same [Like The Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnBfr.png)