# How to fix all 'const' warnings in Android Studio by one action - Flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, warnings

I have the following warnings in Android Studio's Dart Analysis window that get detected in my Flutter code.
I want to fix them all by doing only one action
Is there any approach to do this?

Note that i'm working with Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 2 on MacOS Mojave 10.14.6

[image]

Comment: did you try `dart fix --dry-run` then `dart fix --apply`?

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69193256/10157127)

Comment: @YeasinSheikh you save my day !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They added a feature to the newest Android Studio versions, so we can fix all hints in the same file by one click.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image: Hover in const problem]

[image: after clicking on more options]

Hover on any const warnings and go to more options. Then you will find to fix const warning of that particular file everywhere.
Peace! ✌

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you can see all the warnings by typing in android studio terminal

```
dart fix --dry-run
```

Now if you want everything to be fixed in 1 command then write

```
dart fix --apply
```

It will fix every warning including adding const to your code where needed.

Answer (score -1):

In the root dir of project,
Goto => **analysis_option.yaml** file
in the rules section add:
**prefer_const_constructors : false**

Comment: does this prevent Android studio from showing the warning message? if yes, this is not what I'm searching for, I want to fix them not to hide them

Comment: for better performance you should use const constructors
your solution will make the analyzer prefer non const constructor where const constructors needed